# Velocity: populating a list with dates from "today" to an arbitratily-set point in the past

Tags: loops, velocity

I want to populate a drop-down list with months from the current month to a fixed date in the past using Velocity. I'm not certain if this is possible, since the only loop that is available is foreach and I do not know if there is a sensible way to populate the array the foreach will loop through.

Is this kind of thing simply not something I can do with Velocity? I could achieve it quite easily with Javascript, but for accessibility reasons I'd prefer it to be created by the server.

Comment: Velocity is not the best place for such calculations, it would be more correct to do this on a java side and pass a list of ready to display months to velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can definitely be done.  Check out the DateTool from the VelocityTools project and recall that you can create and populate ArrayLists in VTL:

```
#set( $arr = [1, 2, 'foo', $bar] )
```

or

```
#set( $nums = [1..12] )
```

or directly:

```
#foreach( $num in [1..12] )$num #end  ##this is pretty much a for loop
```

But really, you can also populate the array in java and then drop it into your context.  Often that is better than building model data in your view.